# Webpack - how to compile scss into a separate css file?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, webpack, frontend

I want to use an entry - `materialize.scss` (which imports many other scss files) and to compile it into a separate output - `materialize.min.css` file.

How exactly do I do that with Webpack?

I tried a million different setups with `extract-text-webpack-plugin` along with `css`, `style`, `sass` loader, `node-sass`, `resolve-url-loader` though I'd get different errors, and fixing one just leads to another so... I'm lost!

Comment: Webpack is used to pack JS at first place and styles are required from JS modules. Please, share your JS. If you need to compile styles only you can go some other ways: npm scripts or gulp

Comment: I know what Webpack is and I'm pretty sure it's capable of doing such task without importing styles in the JS. Extract-text-webpack-plugin.

Comment: From [it's readme](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin#usage-example-with-css): `It moves every require("style.css") in entry chunks into a separate css output file.`

Answer (score 3):

This is the webpack.config.js file that I used when i was trying to compile css into a separate file

```
|-- App 
    |-- dist
    |-- src
        |-- css
            |-- header.css
        |-- sass
            |-- img
            |-- partials
                |-- _variables.scss
            |-- main.scss
        |--ts
            |-- tsconfig.json
            |-- user.ts
        |-- main.js
    |-- app.js
    |-- webpack.config.js


var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var extractCss = new ExtractTextPlugin("css/style.css");
var autoprefixer = (require("autoprefixer"))({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] });
var precss = require("precss");
var sugarss = require('sugarss');
var colormin = require('postcss-colormin');
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/sass/main.scss', './src/main.js']
    },
    //devtool:"source-map",
    output:{
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist/"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test:/\.s?(a|c)ss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css!postcss!sass")
            },/*
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader","precss")
            },*/
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                    'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.css")
    ],
    postcss: function(){
      return {
        plugins: [ autoprefixer, precss ]
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Prerequisite

- css-loader
- node-sass
- sass-loader
- style-loader
- extract-text-webpack-plugin

`$ npm install css-loader node-sass sass-loader style-loader extract-text-webpack-plugin --save-dev`

## webpack.config.js

This is my demo `webpack.config.js`, change path based on your project structure:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const srcPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src');
const dstPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dst');

const sassLoaders = [
    'css-loader?minimize',
    'sass-loader?indentedSyntax=sass&includePaths[]=' + srcPath
];

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        client: './src/js/client'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            /*README:https://github.com/babel/babel-loader*/
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                    cacheDirectory: true
                },
                plugins: ['transform-runtime']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!'))
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|bmp)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: dstPath,
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].min.css')
    ]
};
```

And the [demo project](https://github.com/liuwenzhuang/WebpackScssMinify) on GitHub.